# sum the values for different keys with id same in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I would like to know how to sum more than one key values of object for same id in javascript
for same id, how to sum `price` and `total` in my obj
I have tried the code below

```js
var obj = [{
  id: "1",
  price: 100,
  total: 200
}, {
  id: "1",
  price: 100,
  total: 200
}, {
  id: "2",
  price: 10,
  total: 200
}]

let newobj = obj.reduce((a, c) => {
  let filtered = a.filter(el => el.id === c.id);
  if (filtered.length > 0) {
    a[a.indexOf(filtered[0])].price += +c.price;
  } else {
    a.push(c);
  }
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(newobj);
```

Expected Output:

```
result=[{
  id: "1",
  price: 200,
  total: 400
},{
  id: "2",
  price: 10,
  total: 200
}]
```

Comment: And what exactly returns the given code instead? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase thanks for reply,  `total` is not added up

Comment: And what have you tried to debug the problem? Why not start up your debugger and check why the second element is not added properly?

Comment: You just need to add total then,        `[a.indexOf(filtered[0])].price += +c.price;
        a[a.indexOf(filtered[0])].total += +c.total;`

Comment: I'm confused - you already have code to sum one value, what's stopping you adding the *same* code but for the other value?  That's probably the simplest  part of your code compared with reduce/filter.

Comment: @mplungjan it's not even related to this... it's more like OP does't understand multi lines of statements are allowed in if .

Comment: @Raymond Yeah, I saw this later

Answer (score 4):

Instead of [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), you could use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and take the object directly without later having a look up for the index.

If found just add both wanted properties `price` and `total`.

If you like not to mutate the original data, you could take a copy of the object for pushing.

```
a.push({ ...c });
```

```js
var array = [{ id: "1", price: 100, total: 200 }, { id: "1", price: 100, total: 200 }, { id: "2", price: 10, total: 200 }],

result = array.reduce((a, c) => {
  let found = a.find(el => el.id === c.id);
  if (found) {
    found.price += c.price;
    found.total += c.total;
  } else {
    a.push(c);
  }
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: At least this improves the code instead of just making it a typo-type question

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is add the totals as you did the price

```js
var obj = [{
  id: "1",
  price: 100,
  total: 200
}, {
  id: "1",
  price: 100,
  total: 200
}, {
  id: "2",
  price: 10,
  total: 200
}]

let newobj = obj.reduce((a, c) => {
  let filtered = a.filter(el => el.id === c.id);
  if (filtered.length > 0) {
    a[a.indexOf(filtered[0])].price += +c.price;
    a[a.indexOf(filtered[0])].total += +c.total; /* <-- new */
  } else {
    a.push(c);
  }
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(newobj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this with help of [`spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
var obj = [{ id: "1", price: 100, total: 200 },{ id: "1", price: 100, total: 200 },{ id: "2", price: 10, total: 200}]

let newobj = Object.values(obj.reduce((acc,i) => {
    acc[i.id] = acc[i.id] ? {...acc[i.id],price:acc[i.id]['price']+i.price,total:acc[i.id]['total']+i.total} : i;
   return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(newobj)
```